# Режим экзамена в тестирование Android Studio

Tags: android

Переделываю приложение тестирование, нужно создать режим Экзамена. 10 случайных вопросов из всех.
База вопросов из Json файла.
Помогите реализовать, я новичок в этом деле, как не пробовал не получается. Уже бьюсь неделю

```
 private void loadJson() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        //todo: заменить QUESTION_FILE
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(AppConstant.QUESTION_FILEEXAM)));
        String temp;
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(temp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    parseJson(sb.toString());
}

public void parseJson(String jsonData) {
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_QUESTIONNAIRY);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String question = jsonObj.getString(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_QUESTION);
            int correctAnswer = Integer.parseInt(jsonObj.getString(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_CORRECT_ANS));

            JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_ANSWERS);
            ArrayList<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> backgroundColors = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray2.length(); j++) {
                String item_title = jsonArray2.get(j).toString();
                contents.add(item_title);
                backgroundColors.add(AppConstant.COLOR_WHITE);
            }
            mItemList.add(new QuizModel(question, contents, correctAnswer, backgroundColors));
            Collections.shuffle(mItemList);
        }

        mQuestionsCount = mItemList.size();
        Collections.shuffle(mItemList);

        hideLoader();
        updateQuestionsAndAnswers();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showEmptyView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно так нужно. Создавайте.

Comment: да конечно, спасибо за совет.

Comment: Это не совет, это голос за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: Я думал этот форум для помощи, а не для пантов. (Если я сам смог это реализовать, то  не писал бы на этот форум)

Comment: А вы перечитайте свой вопрос и попробуйте из него узнать, в чем собственно заключается ваша проблема. Сейчас он выглядит как "сделайте-ка мне". Причем непонятно что именно.

Comment: Кстати, "панты" это молодые рога оленя, а не то, что вы думаете.

Comment: Я уже Вас понял, забейте на этот вопрос. Вы и так уже много внимания мне уделили. Займитесь другими делами.

Comment: Тут форум для помощи в конкретном вопросе. Если вы не знаете как реализовать тот или иной функционал, задайте конкретный вопрос. Но писать за вас приложение никто не будет. К тому же из вашего вопроса очень трудно понять, что вам вообще нужно. Чем более конкретный вопрос тем больше шансов получить на него ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не взирая на все плохие комментарии, вот мой ответ (как смог). Учитывая что у меня 244 вопроса

```
 public void setNextQuestion() {
    if (isSoundOn) {
        mBeatBox.play(mSounds.get(AppConstant.BUNDLE_KEY_FIRST_INDEX));
    }
    mUserHasPressed = false;
    if (mQuestionPosition < mItemList.size() - 235 && mLifeCounter > 0) {
        mQuestionPosition++;

        if (mQuestionPosition % AppConstant.ADS_INTERVAL == 0) {
        }
        updateQuestionsAndAnswers();
    } else if (mQuestionPosition < mItemList.size() - 235 && mLifeCounter == 0 && mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DialogUtilities dialog = DialogUtilities.newInstance(getString(R.string.reward_dialog_title), getString(R.string.reward_dialog_message), getString(R.string.yes), getString(R.string.no), AppConstant.BUNDLE_KEY_REWARD_OPTION);
        dialog.show(manager, AppConstant.BUNDLE_KEY_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
    } else {
        ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeScoreCardActivity(mActivity, ScoreCardActivity.class, mScore, mWrongAns, mSkip, mResultList, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь нет ни одного плохого комментария. Вам несколько человек указали на некорректность вашего вопроса. И ни один из них никак не оскорблял вас. Раз несколько человек не может понять, что от них хочет спрашивающий, от то стоит задуматься о том как свой вопрос переформулировать, а не писать про "плохие комментарии"